# Map a column from another data frame based on several conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, mapping

Example data

```
Data

[Type]  [Cert Code]  [Cert Desc]  [Data Source]

HP      X1         Logic      Vendor

BA      X2         Disc       Employee

mappingID

[Cert Code]  [Cert Desc]

X3         Logic

X4         Disc
```

So X1 becomes X3 in data

I have this pandas code below which changes Certification Code to Old Certification Code based on description mappings in a second data frame.

The problem is I want to set two conditions whereby it does this only for rows with ‘vendor’ in ‘data source’ column and ‘hp’ in ‘type’ column.  Can anyone help?

```
data['Certification Code'] = data['Certification Description'].map(mappingID.set_index('NEW Certification Description')['OLD Certification Code'])
```

I tried

```
filter = data[(data.Vendor == 'HP') & (data['Data Source'] == 'Vendor')]
```

I get

```
Data

[Type]  [Cert Code]  [Cert Desc]  [Data Source]

HP      X3           Logic      Vendor

BA                   Disc       Employee
```

```
data['Certification Code'] = filter['Certification Description'].map(mappingID.set_index('NEW Certification Description')['OLD Certification Code'])
```

The problem here it turns the Certification Code to blank for the other Vendors in the list.

Desired Outcome

```
Data

[Type]  [Cert Code]  [Cert Desc]  [Data Source]

HP      X3           Logic      Vendor

BA      X2           Disc       Employee
```

Comment: perhaps check out `np.where`, but in any case showing us some sample data, and the desired output would be super helpful.

Comment: Hi I’ve added some example data.  Two data frames called data and mappingID